# have a jquery onclick event show the link in the statusbar on mouse over

Tags: jquery, mouseover, statusbar, alt

Here's the situation:

A basic `onclick` event in jQuery which is bound to a div.

Looks like this:

```
$('#permabox').bind("click", function(){
            var permalink = _functionWhichGetsPermalink();
            window.location.assign(permalink);
        });
```

It works, but if the user mouses over, it will not say to where the user is headed to.

I'd like the div `#permabox` to behave like an anchor, and give the user a message in the statusbar with the `permalink` variable.

Should I create a `mouseover` event? And what should I put in it?
Or should I create an alt attribute to the div? Actually I tried this last one in firebug but nothing showed.

Comment: You can do this by using `window.status="YOUR MESSAGE"`, but be sure if javascript allows to show message in browser settings

Answer (score 0):

If you want a `tooltip` kind of functionality, you can simple add "`title`" to `div`

```
<div id="permabox" title="Your message">

</div>
```

Comment: It would be great if I could add something more discreet that shows up in the statusbar, like a normal link does. Is that something that the "alt" attribute would do? (actually it just occurred to me that maybe I should give up on the `onclick` event, and instead modifiy the `html` content of the div inserting a regular link).

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#hey").attr("title",_functionWhichGetsPermalink());
});
```

Comment: While this can answer the question, it's better to provide some explanations about how this code help.

Comment: it doesn't really answer the question because a tooltip is not what a regular link does; a regular link will show the destination in the status, not as a tooltip. Anyway, I voted this up because it works :) As of my problem, I took down the onclick bind and just used .html() instead, to insert a proper link, which behaves like a link :)

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the ideas! I tried this:

```
var permalink = _functionWhichGetsPermalink();
        alert(permalink);
        $('#permabox').bind("mouseover", function(){window.status=permalink;});
        $("#permabox").attr("title",permalink);
        $('#permabox').bind("click", function(){window.location.assign(permalink);});
```

the tooltip shows correctly, but nothing appears in the statusbar (yes, I have enabled such possibility in the javascript options)